# VSTO Outlook Appointment with FormRegion - save exception when recipient removed

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I created an adjoining Form Region for Outlook appointment items (Using Visual Studio 2019 for Office 2019) and I have inputs on that form from which I capture the values into UserProperties.

Everything works fine until I get to the point where I have added some recipients, sent the meeting request, open it again, remove a recipient, and then try to send an update.

The problem is that on the close event of the form region, I retrieve all my input fields' values, store them in UserProperties, and then fire the item's `.Save()` method, which throws an exception.
When this happens, my UserPropery values are not saved, but the appointments body and the recipient list does indeed save.
When the appointment item is being deleted, the save method will also throw an exception which is understandable. I wrapped it in a try..catch for that.

An example of my code:

```
private void AdditionalAppointmentInfo_FormRegionClosed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (customItem) //In the FormRegionShowing Event, I check for UserProps to see if this is an item created by this add-in
        {
            try
            {
                item.UserProperties["MyUserProperty"].Value = MyTextBox.Text;
                item.Save(); //Throws exception here when a recipient gets removed.
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex){}
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                item.UserProperties.Add("IsCustomItem", OlUserPropertyType.olText).Value="1"; //set a property to indicate that this item was created using this add-in
                item.UserProperties.Add("MyUserProperty", OlUserPropertyType.olText).Value = MyTextBox.Text;
            }
            catch (System.Exception){}

        }
    }
```

I can understand an exception when the appointment item gets deleted, but not one when you remove a recipient.
So while UserProperties works for my intended purposes, is it even the right thing to be using if you want a FormRegion controls' values to persist? Or is there some other way to store persistent user data without having to manually trigger the save method?

Comment: Where did you get the `item` object used in the code sample?

Comment: it was initialized in the FormRegionShowing event like so: `item=(AppointmentItem)this.OutlookItem;`

Answer (score 0):

You must use the [OutlookItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.outlook.formregioncontrol.outlookitem?view=vsto-2017) property to get an Outlook item.

Comment: Do you get any errors in other event handlers? Which exception do you get?

Comment: It just says: 'The item cannot be saved', while the exception when it has been deleted says: 'The item has been deleted or moved'

Comment: I'd recommend choosing another event handler then. Try using the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.close(even)